# How to handle an error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on this login screens. I want the user to be notified when login fails. For example if the user enters the wrong credentials or the server which my app connects to is down it has to show a message login failed.
This is my code so far:

```
-(void)loginSucces
{
    [self showLoginProcess:false];
    PaMainViewController * vc = [[PaMainViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}

-(void)loginFailed
{
    //TODO: handle error
    [self showLoginProcess:false];
    NSLog(@"LoginVC Fail!");
}
```

Comment: Good code formatting helps.

Comment: What's your question?  What do you want to have happen on an error?

Comment: you can use `UIAlertView` to notify user about error or you can use `UILabel` with error message in it. is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope this is what u want..
Use UIAlertView if you just wants to notify the User that login is failed.

```
-(void)loginFailed
{
  //TODO: handle error
  [self showLoginProcess:false];
  NSLog(@"LoginVC Fail!");
  UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"LoginVC Fail!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
  [alert show];
}
```

Comment: adding `delegate:self` without implementing delegate methods will cause application crash.

Comment: Pretty sure it won't crash, but you're right on this : you certainly don't need to add a delegate if you don't plan to use it :)

Comment: `UIAlertView` is deprecated since `iOS 8.0`. You have to use `UIAlertControiller`.

Answer (score 0):

You can display UIAlertView with your message or you can use any third party toast notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach, when network request ends with some result, process that result and show it to user. Usually server provides some user readable information about reason of failure. Same story when for some reason server is not reachable, just take `NSError` and show user a [localizedDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/User_info_dictionary_keys).

Why this way. User will receive some useful information and you will have less headache with localization.

Good example: network is unavailable. In such case `NSerror` `localizedDescription` will provide nice explanation of the problem and user can do respective action like enable WiFi or go outside to restore 3g connection.

Comment: Except that your user is not a software developer and that error message will be more than useless to them. Think about what it means to the user, whether there is a point in showing an error message at all, and whether showing anything other than "sorry, it didn't work" helps at all.

Comment: Most of `NSError`s have `localizedDescription` which is digestible for end user. Also well behaving server also provide error description for end user. For example if there is no network, you will have nice message in all languages, when server doesn't except password you also should receive nice response. Another advantage is that server maintainer can provide some custom messages, like "server is down until 5am". Also if there is big fail than it is easier to receive dissent bug report (doesn't meter that end user can't understand message). Only for some scenario you can provide an exception